# Common code can be used in C and Javascript

Tags: javascript, c, json, client, common-code

For the project, i will recieve data from the server(May be JSON/XML), and there are two individual client application which will process the data to do the similar things. One application will be a web based and the logic will write in JavaScipt, One is about C application. The logic for how to process the data is the same, Is there any way to write the common code using some method can be reused between them.

Answer (score 2):

There exist Javascript implementations that can be called from C code. Using such an implementation, you could write a substantial portion of your code in Javascript, and interface it with C.

One such implementation is [QtScript](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.3/qtscript.html). Qt requires C++, but you can link C and C++ code together easily enough.